# Get Last element in a list in sml foldl

Tags: sml

I am trying to retrieve the last element of a list using **foldl** in SML, and not getting a lot of correct answers from what i have done already, the following is one of my bad tries, any help!

```
            fun last p = foldr ( fn (x, y) => if ( p y ) then x else y ) [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `List.last` even though you should be careful, as it will raise an exception if you use it on an empty list.

For the MosML implementation, you can find the documentation at http://mosml.org/mosmllib/List.html#last-val

Comment: I know it exists in the standard libraries, but i want to implement that function using either foldl or foldr

Answer (score 0):

As RasmusWL mentioned, `List.last` is the appropriate tool for general use.

It can be recreated using `foldl`:

`fun last(alist, init) = List.foldl (fn(x,y) => x) init alist`

This produces a signature: `fn : 'a list * 'a -> 'a`

To write it with `foldr` use:

`fun last(alist, init) = List.foldr (fn(x,y) => x) init (List.rev alist)`

An advantage of using `foldl` is that it does not require a check for an empty list:

```
List.foldl (fn(x,y) => x) 0 [];
(* val it = 0 : int *)
```